# Жесткий диск клиента в терминале Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Как сделать чтобы жесткий диск клиента при подключении через терминал Windows server 2008 отображался в Пуск -> Компьютер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в настройках "Подключение к удаленному компьютеру" (у клиента), нажми параметры - перейди на вкладку локальные ресурсы - в самом низу кнопку подробнее и в окне выбери нужные подключаемые диски при удаленном сеансе.

Answer (score 0):

Либо, если используется AD, то можно в настройках учетки прописать данный диск...